# Find the length of the longest sequence in a matrix

Tags: string, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

**Problem :**

Given a boolean matrix which has only 1s and 0s. Find the length of the longest sequence of continuous 1s. Only movements allowed are South, South-East and East.

**Sample Matrix: with output 5**

```
10000
01111
00100
00010
```

I am trying to solve this problem but haven't reached in understanding the problem to think about a possible solution. Need help in dissecting and understanding the problem.

**Update:**

Please share the correctness.

```
for i=1 to n+1
     N[i][m+1] = 0;
for j=1 to m+1
     N[n+1][j] = 0;
for i=n to 1
     for j=m to 1
          if M[i][j] == 1
                N[i][j] = 1 + max(N[i+1][j] , N[i][j+1]);
          else
                N[i][j] = 0
search max element in matrix, output it.
}
```

**Tried so far**

```
int main()
{
    int A[5][5] = {{0,0,0,1,1},{1,1,1,0,1},{0,1,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{1,1,1,1,1}};
    int temp[5][5];
    int end_r(0), end_c(0);
    for(int i=0; i<;5; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<;5; j++){
            temp[i][j] = A[i][j];
            int top(0), left(0), max(0); 
            if(i>;0) top = temp[i-1][j];
            if(j>;0) left = temp[i][j-1];
            if(top>left) max = top; else max=left;
            if(temp[i][j] && max) {temp[i][j] = ++max, end_r=i; end_c=j;}
            cout<<temp[i][j]<<" ";

        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    int i = end_r, j = end_c, count=temp[i][j];
    --count;
    while(count){    
    if((temp[i-1][j]) == count) --i; else --j;
    --count;
}

    cout<<"Starting Point"<<" "<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
    cout<<"Ending Point"<<" "<<end_r<<" "<<end_c<<endl;
    cout<<"Max Length"<<" "<<temp[end_r][end_c];
    return 0;
}
```

**Solution**

```
/*
============================================================================
Author         : James Chen
Email          : a.james.chen@gmail.com
Description    : Find the longest path of 1s available in the matrix 
Created Date   : 11-July-2013
Last Modified  :
============================================================================
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void DisplayPath(int* matrix, int rows, int cols, int maxCount)
{
    typedef pair<int, int> Pair;
    vector<Pair> path;
    int prevRow = rows;
    int prevCol = cols;
    for(int i = rows - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        for(int j = cols - 1; j >=0; --j){
            if(matrix[ i * cols + j] == maxCount && i <= prevRow && j <= prevCol){
                path.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
                maxCount --;
                prevRow = i;
                prevCol = j;                         
            }

            if(maxCount == 0){
                cout << "The path is " << endl;
                for(int i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                    cout << path.size() - i << "th -- ";
                    cout << "[ " << path[i].first << ", " << path[i].second;
                    cout << "] " << endl;
                }

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int FindLongest1Sequences(int* matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    assert(matrix != NULL);
    assert(rows > 0);
    assert(cols > 0);

    int maxCount(0);
    int count(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            int a = (i == 0) ? 0 : matrix[(i - 1) * cols + j];
            int b = (j == 0) ? 0 : matrix[i * cols + j - 1];
            matrix[i * cols + j] = matrix[i * cols + j] ? max(a, b) + 1 : 0;
            maxCount = max(maxCount, matrix[i * cols + j]);
        }
    }

    DisplayPath(matrix, rows, cols, maxCount);

    return maxCount;
}

void DoTest(int* matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    if(matrix == NULL){
        cout << "The matix is null" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(rows < 1){
        cout << "The rows of matix is less than 1" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(cols < 1){
        cout << "The cols of matix is less than 1" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "The matrix is " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
            cout << setw(3) << matrix[i * cols + j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int len = FindLongest1Sequences(matrix, rows, cols);
    cout << "The longest length is " << len << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------" << endl;

}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int matrix[5][5] = {
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };

    DoTest(&matrix[0][0], 5, 5);        // Expected return 8

    int matrix1[1][1] = {
        0
    };
    DoTest(&matrix1[0][0], 1, 1);       // Expected return 0

    int matrix2[1][1] = {
        1
    };
    DoTest(&matrix2[0][0], 1, 1);       // Expected return 1

    int matrix3[5][5] = {
        0
    };

    DoTest(&matrix3[0][0], 5, 5);       // Expected return 0

    int matrix4[5][5] = {
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };

    DoTest(&matrix4[0][0], 5, 5);       // Expected return 9

    int matrix5[5][5] = {
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 
        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
        {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
    };

    DoTest(&matrix5[0][0], 5, 5);       // Expected return 7

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
The matrix is
  0  0  0  1  1
  1  1  1  0  1
  0  1  1  1  0
  0  0  1  0  0
  1  1  1  1  1
The path is
1th -- [ 1, 0]
2th -- [ 1, 1]
3th -- [ 2, 1]
4th -- [ 2, 2]
5th -- [ 3, 2]
6th -- [ 4, 2]
7th -- [ 4, 3]
8th -- [ 4, 4]
The longest length is 8
---------------------------------------
The matrix is
  0
The longest length is 0
---------------------------------------
The matrix is
  1
The path is
1th -- [ 0, 0]
The longest length is 1
---------------------------------------
The matrix is
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0
The longest length is 0
---------------------------------------
The matrix is
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
The path is
1th -- [ 0, 0]
2th -- [ 1, 0]
3th -- [ 2, 0]
4th -- [ 3, 0]
5th -- [ 4, 0]
6th -- [ 4, 1]
7th -- [ 4, 2]
8th -- [ 4, 3]
9th -- [ 4, 4]
The longest length is 9
---------------------------------------
The matrix is
  1  1  0  1  1
  0  1  1  0  1
  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  0  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
The path is
1th -- [ 2, 0]
2th -- [ 3, 0]
3th -- [ 4, 0]
4th -- [ 4, 1]
5th -- [ 4, 2]
6th -- [ 4, 3]
7th -- [ 4, 4]
The longest length is 7
---------------------------------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Ref** : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence
https://sites.google.com/site/spaceofjameschen/annnocements/findthelongestpathof1savailableinthematrix--goldmansachs

Comment: You are just dropping a requirement here; but we expect you to show us that you tried solving the problem yourself. Paste your code here and we will see what's wrong in it and guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I have updated my assumption. I am looking for a understandable thought process on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? You dumped some code but it is not clear what problem do you have? Also this is not a code, but just some sort of pseudocode. P.S. it looks like you are trying to cheat in a programming contest. If not - show where you got the problem (a friend of my friend shared this with me and now I am curious most of the time means that "I try to cheat, but really do not want you to know that I am cheating")

Comment: lol. When I ask a problem people say you are suppose to show what you have tried. When I google google find some code which is close to solve the problem. People say I am dumping some code for a challenge. How can I participate in a challenge i m trying hard to understand a problem and try to write a optimal solution.

Comment: Looking for optimal solution with best time and space complexity

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic programming problem. Imagine that you have solved the problem for until row i and column j. And for every row < i, and every column on row i which is less than j you have the answer stored in DP[][].

Now, you should look at it as induction. The best possible answer for DP[i][j] can come from these three places (if they exist - meaning that they are valid indices and M[i][j] == 1):

```
DP[i - 1][j] (a south move from there to i, j)
DP[i - 1][j - 1] (a south east move from there)
DP[i][j - 1] (an east move from there)
```

The code (the first code) that you put is trying to simulate this but actually does not give a proper solution for this test case (because it fails to capture the south-east move):

```
100
010
001
```

In fact, your first codes needs to be like this:

```
N[i][j] = 1 + max(N[i+1][j] , N[i][j+1], N[i + 1][j + 1]);
```

Note that N[i][j] is like DP[i][j] that I described. However, I described DP the way the problem is, i.e. moving south, south-east, east. But N[][] is solving the problem other way around, i.e., it is starting from the bottom-right corner and moves west, west-north, north. However, it actually does not matter; they will both provide the same solution. (It is a good exercise to see why)